# Spring MVC, Why am I getting a 404 error?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I cannot figure out why I am getting a 404 error despite literally hours of looking.

```
HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
Type Status Report

Message /

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Apache Tomcat/9.0.24
```

I have a very simple spring MVC applications but I seriously can't see what the error is. Please help I'm losing my mind

Structure:

SpringMVCDemo

- src

  - main

    - java

      - com.springmvc.demo

        - HomeController.java
  - WEB-INF

    - view

      - main-menu.jsp
  - spring-mvc-demo-servlet.xml
  - web.xml

My Controller:
HomeController.java

```
package com.springmvc.demo;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

@RequestMapping("/")
public String showMyPage(){
    return "main-menu"; // view name
}
```

My View:
main-menu.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2> Spring MVC Demo - main-menu</h2>

</body>
</html>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">

<display-name>spring-mvc-demo</display-name>

<absolute-ordering />

<!-- Spring MVC Configs -->

<!-- Step 1: Configure Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/spring-mvc-demo-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<!-- Step 2: Set up URL mapping for Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

spring-mvc-demo-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

<!-- Step 3: Add support for component scanning -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.springmvc.demo" />

<!-- Step 4: Add support for conversion, formatting and validation support -->
<mvc:annotation-driven/>

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: Can you please add the url that you are trying to navigate?

Comment: It's run with tomcat the url is: Localhost:8081

Comment: And if you try with `localhost:8081/Home` what do you get?

Comment: How did you deploy it to Tomcat? Also, did you check the Tomcat logs to see if the webapp started ok? Just because Tomcat started ok doesn't mean your webapp did.

Comment: /Home also gives a 404 error.

Comment: I deployed to tomcat by linking in intelij https://i.imgur.com/EmphOnW.png

Comment: @Andreas I'm pretty sure it deployed correctly I see this in the end of the logs

[2019-10-30 09:56:01,836] Artifact SpringMVCdemo:war exploded: Artifact is deployed successfully

30-Oct-2019 21:56:07.237 INFO [Catalina-utility-2] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\manager] has finished in [49] ms

Comment: `SpringMVCdemo.war`? So the webapp was deployed with context path `/SpringMVCdemo`? Did you try `http://localhost:8081/SpringMVCdemo/`?

Comment: @Andreas SpringMVCdemo:war exploded and yeah I tried the /SpringMVCdemo too same result, 404 error

Comment: @Andreas Thanks for trying to help it randomly got fixed by remaking my artifact.. weird. but thanks! you made me re-try stuff like that!

Answer (score 0):

In this case my issue was solved by re-creating my artifact SpringMVCdemo:war exploded from modules.

I do not fully understand what was wrong to begin with but hopefully that helps someone in future